# Image dosen't load when visit website in first time

Tags: html, css

I have website: [click](http://tombit.suszek.info/) and the problem is. When I visit this website for the first time. I don't see image slider. But when I reload the page the image is correctly display. I don't know where is the problem and this is the worst. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Image never loads for me and this is in console `Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later.`

Comment: try to put that slider inside $(document).ready hope that  will solve the issue.

Comment: Try loading all your js files at the bottom just before the closing body tag </body>, and make sure jQuery is ahead of anything that requires it. I reckon jQuery is loading after your slider which makes it not show. The image shows fine when js is not on, so try this, it should work. Also validate all your html here and fix all the errors, that will help: https://validator.nu/

Comment: unrelated to answer if there is only one image then why use a slider. your code also is restricting the slider to only 1 image with maxSlide:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this to mainPageOne class & try:

```
.mainPageOne 
{
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your #homepage-slider doesn't have a height or width, and the overflow is hidden, so nothing can be shown since everything is inside #homepage-slider. The image is definitely there, I can see it when I inspect the element. And by making all of the elements inside of #homepage-slider have a width & height of 100%, I can see the image and all of the decorative text/buttons.